# Make the uninstall registry key conditional via code

Tags: inno-setup

How do you make Inno Setup disable [`CreateUninstallRegKey`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createuninstallregkey) via code?

My **setup.exe** file created in Inno Setup accepts parameters, e.g.:

```
setup.exe -a
```

or

```
setup.exe -b
```

If `-a` parameter is supplied, then enable `CreateUninstallRegKey`, or if `-b` parameter is supplied, then disable `CreateUninstallRegKey`.

Is there anyway to set `CreateUninstallRegKey` via code or do I have to make a function then call the function in script section?

This [help page](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm) explains about using `{code:...}` constants, but unfortunately I got this error:

[image: Screenshot of the code and error message]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use the `{code:}` expression for passing values to Boolean type directives. Do it this way:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
CreateUninstallRegKey=NeedsUninstallRegKey

[Code]
function CmdLineParamExists(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;  
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
    if CompareText(ParamStr(I), Value) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
end;

function NeedsUninstallRegKey: Boolean;
begin
  Result := CmdLineParamExists('-a');
end;
```

Comment: what if I want a variable use instead of the function name?

Comment: With variable you're out of luck. You can use only function for this. But you can make a simple getter function in which you'll just return the value of a certain variable.